# microservice based event store

Tags: microservices, cqrs, event-sourcing

Unfamiliar with all the details of domain driven design, would it make sense  in a microservice architecture to think of each service as it's own domain and in turn build an event store per service?

Not totally sure what the trade-offs might be from a single monolithic event store for the entire system. For example, more difficulty replaying conditions in the system or debugging cross service dependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key thing is to have an unambiguous single owner - i.e. if you share a store, that's fine, as long as only one service ever uses a given set of streams.

In NEventStore v5+ for example, this is codified in having a "bucket" be a subdivision within a store - each service gets an isolated set of state that way. Or one might do the same via multiple SCHEMAs in a SQL SB.

There are of course lots of good reasons to separate to the max too

- you don't want to leave people open to temptation to read cross service
- you want to enable the services to go Separate Ways - you don't want to have any infrastructure change for Service B to require a deploy of Service A
- having a shared lib, which can go hand in hand with this view, is also a slipperly slope

It should be said that this concern is a general constraint in line with the autonomy tenet of microservices (and SOA before it)

Comment: Is it permitted for a consumer (read model) to listen to multiple event stores in order to build a complex projection?

Comment: Well.... there is no 'allowed'. But the general advice is that any integration between microservices is an interface to which things get coupled, with all the pain of understanding, analysing and versioning that over time. As such each and every one should be modeled explicitly - i.e. you'd build something that explicitly surfaces any events that others need - if you don't you'll have a ball of mud as fast as with any other architecture. (Which is why the general advice is to never just stamp out N services using the exact same infra - model each service/context appropriately and individually)

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU Sorry, forgot to @ you in

Comment: What do you mean by "you don't want to leave people open to temptation to read cross service"?

Comment: I think this means it might be too easy to do the equivalent of a SQL JOIN where you grab data from some other service because it's easy to do so if sharing db

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU It's easier to remove chocolate from your diet if you don't have a bowl of it on your table / in your office. I'm essentially making a slippery slope argument as tom says -- same way there are good arguments for putting every service in a separate repo (vs e.g. `.sln`). The same way one does not need project files to manage dependencies - you can 'Just' use NDepend to enforce your cross-namespace constraints and it's the same thing in theory ;)